# Polygon Clipping not working when using Sutherland-Hodgman Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, netbeans, polygon, clipping

I am writing a program that creates a polygon that is shaped like a fish and fills it with green. There are buttons to move the this fish around inside of a window. I want to have only the parts of the fish that are inside of the window to be visible so I am attempting to implement the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm to do this.

I am not positive where I am going wrong. All I know is that when I come in contact with an edge of the window, I end up with lines going to places they shouldn't.

For example:

The first picture is before it hits an edge and the second is when the fish hits the top edge of the window:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code that I have written to implement the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm for polygon clipping:

```
int left_most_edge, right_most_edge, scan = 0;
double wxl = 50, wxh = 362, wyl = 246, wyh = 62;
double[][] table = new double[4][200];  //2d array containing: 
                                        //[0][-] -> ymax, [1][-] -> ymin, [2][-] -> dx, [3][-] -> x
double[] px = {100, 150, 200, 210, 215, 205, 215, 210, 200, 150}; //contains all x coord.
double[] py = {125, 100, 120, 110, 115, 125, 135, 140, 130, 150}; //contains all y coord.
double[] xout = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
double[] yout = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int outnum;
double[] lastl = new double[2];
double[] lastr = new double[2];
double[] lastt = new double[2];
double[] lastb = new double[2];
boolean drawAgain = false;

public void clipPolygon(Graphics g, int number_entered_edges) 
{//clips the polygon so only parts that are in the viewing window get filled
    lastl[0] = px[number_entered_edges - 1];
    lastl[1] = py[number_entered_edges - 1];

    lastr[0] = wxl;
    lastb[0] = wxl;
    lastt[0] = wxl;
    lastr[1] = wyl;
    lastb[1] = wyl;
    lastt[1] = wyl;

    outnum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_entered_edges; i++) 
    {
        clipL(px[i], py[i]);
    }//end for

    outnum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number_entered_edges; i++) 
    {
        clipL(px[i], py[i]);
    }//end for
}//end clipPolygon

public void clipL(double x, double y) 
{//clips from the left
    if ((lastl[0] < wxl && wxl <= x) || (x <= wxl && wxl < lastl[0])) 
    {
        System.out.println("Passed into clipR -> (" + wxl + ", " + ((((y - lastl[1]) * (wxl - x)) / x - lastl[0]) + y) + ")");
        System.out.println(y + " - " + lastl[1] + " * " + "(" + wxl + " - " + x + ") / " + x + " - " + lastl[0] + " + " + y + ")");
        clipR(wxl, ((((y - lastl[1]) * (wxl - x)) / x - lastl[0]) + y));
        drawAgain = true;
    }//end if

    lastl[0] = x;
    lastl[1] = y;

    if (wxl < x)
        clipR(x, y);
}//end clipL

public void clipR(double x, double y)
{//clips from the right
    System.out.println("herro: " + x + ", " + y);
    if ((x <= wxh && wxh < lastr[0]) || (lastr[0] < wxh && wxh <= x)) 
    {
        clipB(wxh, ((((y - lastr[1]) * (wxh - x)) / x - lastr[0]) + y));
        drawAgain = true;
    }//end if

    lastr[0] = x;
    lastr[1] = y;

    if (x < wxh)
        clipB(x, y);
}//end clipR

public void clipB(double x, double y) 
{//clips from the bottom
    if ((lastb[1] < wyl && wyl <= y) || (y <= wyl && wyl < lastb[1]))
    {
        clipT(((((x - lastb[0]) * (wyl - y)) / y - lastb[1]) + x), wyl);
        drawAgain = true;
    }//end if

    lastb[0] = x;
    lastb[1] = y;

    if (wyl > y)
        clipT(x, y);
}//end clipB

public void clipT(double x, double y) 
{//clips from the top
    if ((lastt[1] > wyh && wyh >= y) || y >= wyh && wyh > lastt[1])
    {
        store(((((x - lastt[0]) * (wyh - y)) / y - lastt[1]) + x), wyh);
           drawAgain = true;
    }//end if
    lastt[0] = x;
    lastt[1] = y;

    if (wyh < y)
        store(x, y);
}//end clipT

public void store(double x, double y) 
{//stores the final coordinates after clipping
    xout[outnum] = x;
    yout[outnum] = y;
    outnum++;
}//end store

public void drawMyPolygon(Graphics g) 
{ //draws the polygon
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine((int) px[0], (int) py[0], (int) px[1], (int) py[1]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[1], (int) py[1], (int) px[2], (int) py[2]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[2], (int) py[2], (int) px[3], (int) py[3]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[3], (int) py[3], (int) px[4], (int) py[4]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[4], (int) py[4], (int) px[5], (int) py[5]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[5], (int) py[5], (int) px[6], (int) py[6]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[6], (int) py[6], (int) px[7], (int) py[7]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[7], (int) py[7], (int) px[8], (int) py[8]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[8], (int) py[8], (int) px[9], (int) py[9]);
    g.drawLine((int) px[9], (int) py[9], (int) px[0], (int) py[0]);
}//end drawMyPolygon

public void drawNewPolygon(Graphics g)
{ //draw a new polygon with the coordinates of the clipped polygon
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[0], (int) yout[0], (int) xout[1], (int) yout[1]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[1], (int) yout[1], (int) xout[2], (int) yout[2]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[2], (int) yout[2], (int) xout[3], (int) yout[3]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[3], (int) yout[3], (int) xout[4], (int) yout[4]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[4], (int) yout[4], (int) xout[5], (int) yout[5]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[5], (int) yout[5], (int) xout[6], (int) yout[6]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[6], (int) yout[6], (int) xout[7], (int) yout[7]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[7], (int) yout[7], (int) xout[8], (int) yout[8]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[8], (int) yout[8], (int) xout[9], (int) yout[9]);
    g.drawLine((int) xout[9], (int) yout[9], (int) xout[0], (int) yout[0]);
    drawAgain = false;
}//end drawNewPolygon

public void drawMyHorizontalLine(Graphics g, int x1, int y, int x2) 
{ //draws the line for filling
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);
}//end drawMyHorizontalLine

public void drawWindow(Graphics g) 
{//draws the viewing window
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine((int)wxl, (int)wyh, (int)wxl, (int)wyl);
    g.drawLine((int)wxl, (int)wyh, (int)wxh, (int)wyh);
    g.drawLine((int)wxl, (int)wyl, (int)wxh, (int)wyl);
    g.drawLine((int)wxh, (int)wyh, (int)wxh, (int)wyl);
}//end drawWindow

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{   
    super.paint(g);

    //draw viewing window
    drawWindow(g);

    //initialize the edge table to all zeroes
    initializeTable();

    //clip the polygon
    clipPolygon(g, 10);

    System.out.println("Coordinates:");
    System.out.println("(" + px[0] + ", " + py[0] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[1] + ", " + py[1] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[2] + ", " + py[2] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[3] + ", " + py[3] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[4] + ", " + py[4] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[5] + ", " + py[5] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[6] + ", " + py[6] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[7] + ", " + py[7] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[8] + ", " + py[8] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + px[9] + ", " + py[9] + ")");

    System.out.println("\nStored:");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[0] + ", " + yout[0] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[1] + ", " + yout[1] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[2] + ", " + yout[2] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[3] + ", " + yout[3] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[4] + ", " + yout[4] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[5] + ", " + yout[5] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[6] + ", " + yout[6] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[7] + ", " + yout[7] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[8] + ", " + yout[8] + ")");
    System.out.println("(" + xout[9] + ", " + yout[9] + ")");

    for (int i = 0; i < xout.length; i++)
        System.out.println("outnum -> " + outnum);

    //draw polygon with red outline
    if (drawAgain)
    {
        fillMyPolygon(g, 10, 10);
        drawNewPolygon(g);
    }//end if
    else
    {
        fillMyPolygon(g, 10, 10);
        drawMyPolygon(g);
    }//end else

    //set buttons to visible
    buttons();
}//end paint
```

Let me know if you have any ideas or maybe need more information. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest stepping through this with your debugger.

Comment: Check the algorithm here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Euuw72Ymu0M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the algorithm was something as simple as missing parenthesis to separate different parts of the formulas that determined the new coordinates of the clipped lines. It functioned well after that was resolved.